# What are levels in a pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I've been reading through the documentation and many explanations and examples use `levels` as something taken for granted. Imho the docs lack a bit on a fundamental explanation of the data structure and definitions.

What are levels in a data frame? What are levels in a `MultiIndex` index?

Comment: check out [categorial data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html)

Comment: I think playing with `stack`, `unstack` and `pivot` would be helpful in addition to reading the docs.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I stumbled across this question while analyzing the answer to [my own question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50109058/672018), but I didn't find the John's answer satisfying enough. After a few experiments though I think I understood the levels and decided to share:

**Short answer:**

Levels are parts of the index or column.

**Long answer:**

I think this multi-column `DataFrame.groupby` example illustrates the index levels quite nicely.

Let's say we have the time logged on issues report data:

```
report = pd.DataFrame([
        [1, 10, 'John'],
        [1, 20, 'John'],
        [1, 30, 'Tom'],
        [1, 10, 'Bob'],
        [2, 25, 'John'],
        [2, 15, 'Bob']], columns = ['IssueKey','TimeSpent','User'])

   IssueKey  TimeSpent  User
0         1         10  John
1         1         20  John
2         1         30   Tom
3         1         10   Bob
4         2         25  John
5         2         15   Bob
```

The index here has only 1 level (there is only one index value identifying every row). The index is artificial (running number) and consists of values form 0 to 5.

Say we want to merge (sum) all logs created by **the same user** to **the same issue** (to get the total time spent on the issue by the user)

```
time_logged_by_user = report.groupby(['IssueKey', 'User']).TimeSpent.sum()

IssueKey  User
1         Bob     10
          John    30
          Tom     30
2         Bob     15
          John    25
```

Now our data index has 2 levels, as multiple users logged time to the same issue. The levels are `IssueKey` and `User`. The levels are parts of the index (only together they can identify a row in a DataFrame / Series).

Levels being parts of the index (as a tuple) can be nicely observed in the Spyder Variable explorer:

[image]

Having levels gives us opportunity to aggregate values within groups in respect to an index part (**level**) of our choice. E.g. if we want to assign the max time spent on an issue by any user, we can:

```
max_time_logged_to_an_issue = time_logged_by_user.groupby(level='IssueKey').transform('max')

IssueKey  User
1         Bob     30
          John    30
          Tom     30
2         Bob     25
          John    25
```

Now the first 3 rows have the value `30`, as they correspond to the issue `1` (`User` level was ignored in the code above). The same story for the issue `2`.

This can be useful e.g. if we want to find out which users spent most time on every issue:

```
issue_owners = time_logged_by_user[time_logged_by_user == max_time_logged_to_an_issue]

IssueKey  User
1         John    30
          Tom     30
2         John    25
```

Answer (score 19):

Usually a DataFrame has a 1D index and columns:

```
    x y
0   4 1
1   3 9
```

Here the index is [0, 1] and the columns are ['x', 'y'].  But you can have multiple levels in either the index or the columns:

```
    x y
    a b c
0 7 4 1 3
  8 3 9 5
```

Here the columns' first level is ['x', 'y', 'y'] and the second level is ['a', 'b', 'c'].  The index's first level is [0, 0] and the second level is [7, 8].

Comment: This answer is very helpful for explicitly delineating the difference between "index levels" and "column levels". I had a DF with a single index level and multiple column levels and this answer helped me understand it!

Comment: How can I select the column with first level y and second b ?